# How to prevent registration if Password and Confirm Password are not the same

Tags: node.js, passwords, middleware

I have a simple registration form as follows:

```
<div class ="container form">

<div class="jumbotron form"><h2><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Signup</h2></div>
<form action = "/register" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter username" name="username"> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <label for="password1">Password</label>
        <input id="password1" type = "password" class ="form-control" placeholder = "Enter password" name="password1">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <label for="password2">Confirm password</label>
        <input id="password2" type = "password" class ="form-control" placeholder = "Enter password" name = "password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <label for="img">Image</label>
        <input type = "text" class ="form-control" placeholder = "Enter image URL" name = "image">
</div>
    <button id="submit-login" type ="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Signup</button>
</form>
</div>
```

My register route looks like this:

```
router.post("/register", function(req, res){
var newUser = new User({username: req.body.username, image: req.body.image});
User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
if(err){
    res.redirect("/blogs");
    console.log(err);
} 
passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
    res.redirect("/blogs");
});
});
})
```

I need to throw an error if the password fields don't match to prevent user registration. I figured it might be best to write some middleware and insert it in the register route, but I've been playing around with code and cannot quite work out how to write this middleware. Can anybody help?

My thoughts are that this requires some kind of if statement along the lines of if(document.getElementById("password1").value != document.getElementById("password2").value  then hijack the POST route, but not sure how to write it or where to insert it in the code?

Update: I still don't have a solution for this.

I've now tried the following in my JS file but it doesn't work either:

```
$('#submit-login').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if($('#password1').val() !== $('#password2').val());
    alert("Passwords don't match!")
}
)
```

Anyone able to advise?

Comment: Aren't you already doing exactly that? In `if(err){}`? Just output to the page rather than the console.

Comment: but at the moment, the password confirm input isn't being compared to the password input. It doesn't go anywhere

Comment: It seems like `passport.authenticate` should be in an `else` statement. However, the redirect should happen anyway, as you're redirecting in both the error and lack of error. I can only assuming you're passing incorrect data to `/register`. Are you getting any error messages? Could you post the code for `/register` as well please?

Comment: /register is just the registration form so essentially I want to redirect back to the same page when the passwords don't match and then I'd add in a flash message ultimately to explain what's happened. I still feel the problem though is that at the moment the password confirmation input doesn't do anything - there's nothing in my code to check if the 2 password inputs match so guess it will never throw an error? I figured I should have a middleware of some sort to say if(document.getElementById("password1").value != document.getElementById("password2").value , then hijack the register route?