# Need to throw error of 'password' and 'confirm password' do not match

Tags: node.js, routes, passwords

I have a simple registration form as follows:

```
<div class ="container form">

<div class="jumbotron form"><h2><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Signup</h2></div>
<form action = "/register" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter username" name="username"> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<label for="password1">Password</label>
    <input id="password1" type = "password" class ="form-control" placeholder = "Enter password" name="password1">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<label for="password2">Confirm password</label>
    <input id="password2" type = "password" class ="form-control" placeholder = "Enter password" name = "password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<label for="img">Image</label>
    <input type = "text" class ="form-control" placeholder = "Enter image URL" name = "image">
</div>
<button id="submit-login" type ="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Signup</button>
</form>
</div>
```

My registration route looks as follows:

```
router.post("/register", function(req, res){
var newUser = new User({username: req.body.username, image: req.body.image});
User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
if(err){
res.redirect("/blogs");
console.log(err);
 } 
passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
res.redirect("/blogs");
});
}); 
})
```

I need to throw an error if the password fields don't match to prevent user registration. I figured it might be best to write some middleware and insert it in the register route, but I've been playing around with code and cannot quite work out how to write this middleware. Can anybody help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent registration if Password and Confirm Password are not the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43080130/how-to-prevent-registration-if-password-and-confirm-password-are-not-the-same)

Comment: If your question hasn't had any traction then update it with some more detail, please don't post it again.

Answer (score 0):

create an "err" array and push errors into it, if condition is true.
Include the following validation....

```
const err = [];
if( req.body.password1 !== req.body.password2 ){
   err.push( {msg: "passwords do not match!! ") });
}
if( err.length > 0 ){
  console.log(err);
  res.render("/register");     
}
```

So,your register route will look like..

```
router.post("/register", function(req, res){
    var newUser = new User({username: req.body.username, image: req.body.image});
    const err = [];
    if( req.body.password1 !== req.body.password2 ){
       errors.push( {msg: "passwords do not match!! ") });
    }
    if(err.length > 0){
      console.log(err);
      res.render("/register");
    }
    else{
      User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
      if(err){
      res.redirect("/blogs");
      console.log(err);
      } 
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
      res.redirect("/blogs");
      });
     }); 
    }
  });
```